# Counting instances of an entry in one table from another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two sql tables site and  sms

The structure is ROUGHLY like

```
SENEGAL_SITE:

siteID   Lon        Lat
1        11.232      12.32
2        12.232      12.42
3        11.232      12.62
4        11.232      11.42
```

ATA_SMS_Apr:

```
  out_going_site_id  inSite  no_sms
         4            1         65
         2            4         21
         3            4         54
```

i want to query out a result somthing like this

```
site id     SMS_Site_count
1               5
2               3
3               1
```

So basically I want to count the number of sms through each site tower

The query which I used to do this is this

```
select *  ,
count((select * 
       from ATA_SMS_Apr a 
       where s.site_id=a.out_going_site_id)) 
from SENEGAL_SITE s
```

Doing this I get a error as `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: Please post some sample data and results that agree with each other. It will be much easier for someone to recreate the situation and help you.

Comment: Can you possibly make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Also I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "count the number of SMS through each site tower".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a correlated subquery to get the sms count from ATA_SMS_Apr table for each site id

The count is moved inside the subquery from outside.

```
select * ,
(select count(*) 
 from ATA_SMS_Apr a 
 where s.site_id=a.out_going_site_id) as SMS_Site_Count
from SENEGAL_SITE s
```